# Variable from array comes back as Undefined

Tags: arraylist, google-apps-script

```
var activeSP = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheets ;
  var currentSheet; 
  var sheetName ;

  for(i = 0; (activeSP.getNumSheets()-1) != 0;i++) {

    sheets = activeSP.getSheets();
    currentSheet = sheets[i] ; //Where i think the error is
    sheetName = currentSheet.getSheetName() ;

    if(sheetName != dailyName) {
      activeSP.deleteSheet(currentSheet) ;
      }
    else {
    i++
    }
  }
}
```

I have this script. The idea is to delete all the sheets but the sheet with the desired name(dailyName). But when i try to make **currentSheet** the current value for the ArrayList it comes back as undefined. If somebody could help me i would aprreciate it a lot. This is for work no even for school.

> Error:TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetName" of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're calling `getSheets()` in each step of the loop. Also, when you're deleting items from an array, it's more efficient to work backwards so your loop doesn't return to index 0 on each pass.

Here's a working function:

```js
function sheetToDelete() {
  var activeSP = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dailyName = "img"; // Set this somewhere

  var sheets ;
  var currentSheet; 
  var sheetName ;

  // Get the sheets as an array
  sheets = activeSP.getSheets();

  // run the loop backwards
  for(var i = (sheets.length - 1); i >= 0; --i) {

    // get the name of the current index
    currentSheet = sheets[i].getName();

    // Test for a match. If it doesn't delete the sheet
    if(dailyName !== currentSheet) {
      // currentSheet is a string right now, so use the index position
      activeSP.deleteSheet(sheets[i]) 
    }     
  }
}
```

You also don't need the `else` statement in the loop because it will move to the next item the array if the conditional is not matched.

Comment: That solved the problem thank you so much!! i really need to review my array lists :/